# How to append a chunk of html to a loaded html page using window.open() method

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to append a chunk of html to a loaded html page via window.open() method.
for this example the chunk of html will be a string.

```
var w = window.open('mypage.html, 'windowname', 'scrollbars=yes,location=no,toolbar=no,status=no,width=500,height=550,left=300,top=50');
var htmlChunk = '<span>bla bla</span>'
 $(w.document.body).append( htmlChunk );
```

$(w.document.body) doesn't seem to be able to get to the body tag on the mypage.html inside the popup.

I also tried using a ready method.

```
 $(w.document.body).ready(function(){
         $(this).find('body').append(htmlChunk);
     });
```

This didn't work either it was appending it to the window below the popup.

Just to be clear here i'm not looking to add any JS to mypage.html directly. I need to be able to access the popup mypage.html body tag and append a chunk of html to that.
My setup, I have a js file inside a main.html page. In the main.html page I have link that has a click event on it which is setup inside the js file. This is where I call the popup and I capture a block of html from the main.html page to append to the mypage.html inside the popup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
$(w).on("load", function(){
    $("body", w.document).append( htmlChunk );
});
```

The onload event handler makes the code wait until the new window has been created, and using `w.document` as jQuery's second argument sets the context on the new window. You cannot run a jQuery instance from the child window because it doesn't load jQuery.

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I'm after Álvaro.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaking the $()-operator in jQuery should run when the page is "ready". So you could try to simplify your code a bit?

I would do it like this:

```
$(function(){
    $("body").append("This is the string you send in");
});
```

Comment: I don't think you are understanding my example. I need to be able to append outside the loaded html file, your method is adding the js to the loaded html page. Sorry maybe I'm not clear. I need to access the loaded page from the w variable and append the htmlBlock to the body of the loaded page.

Comment: What are your trying to make? A popup of some sort? If that's the case, this seems to be a very complicated way of doing it.

Comment: See my new comments at the bottom of my post.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var output = "data";
        var OpenWindow = window.open("mypage.html", "mywin", '');
        OpenWindow.dataFromParent = output; // dataFromParent is a variable in mypage.html
        OpenWindow.init();
    });
</script>
```

in mypage.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var dataFromParent;    
    function init() {
        document.write(dataFromParent);
    }
</script>
```

If you need the code to run after the new window's DOM is ready try this:

```
var OpenWindow = window.open("mypage.html", "mywin", '');
$(OpenWindow.document.body).ready(function() {
    $(OpenWindow.document.body).append('<p>hi</p>');
});
```

Comment: Any way of doing without adding js to the mypage.html. Can't I access the mypage.html from the w variable. I can access it directly if I don't load mypage.html and just use a open empty popup by using this. $(w.document.body).append( htmlChunk );

Comment: I tried your code by adding the js to mypage.html which I don't really want to do but I get a error trying to access OpenWindow.init()

Comment: Thanks Deep but I already tried that in my post above. I just used $(this) inside the ready function instead of your $(OpenWindow.document.body) but both don't work for me. Also OpenWindow.init(); will cause an error. "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object global] has no method 'init' "